# Caffe C++ save network caffemodel file

Tags: c++, deep-learning, caffe

I have successfully built and trained an audioCaffe demo, but the demo doesn't save the network.

I have found documentation for saving the network in Python in MatLab, but I can't find any documentation on C++.

I would think there would be a similar function like `net.save("file.caffemodel")` but I tried that and it didn't work.

In the train function in `caffe.cpp` I tried this:

```
  if (FLAGS_snapshot.size()) {
    LOG(INFO) << "Resuming from " << FLAGS_snapshot;
    solver.Solve(FLAGS_snapshot);
  } else if (FLAGS_weights.size()) {
    LOG(INFO) << "Finetuning from " << FLAGS_weights;
    solver.net()->CopyTrainedLayersFrom(FLAGS_weights);
    solver.Solve();
  } else {
    solver.Solve();
  }
  solver.save("file.caffemodel")
```

But I got a `no method exists error`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this...

```
caffe::NetParameter net_param;
net_->ToProto(&net_param);
caffe::WriteProtoToBinaryFile(net_param, caffe_model_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `Snapshot()` and `SnapshotToBinaryProto()` - src/caffe/solver.cpp.
Caller code is in Solver::Step:

```
// Save a snapshot if needed.
    if ((param_.snapshot()
         && iter_ % param_.snapshot() == 0
         && Caffe::root_solver()) ||
         (request == SolverAction::SNAPSHOT)) {
      Snapshot();
    }
```